# Trying to solve python problem with binary search

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image]Hey I am trying to solve this python practice question but my solution is not under the given time limit can someone please explain. It will be very helpful of yours because no where I can find this python solution of this question and their they have given solution in Java which is almost same to mine

https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/searching/binary-search/practice-problems/algorithm/victory-over-power-4a0cb459/description/

```
tasks_count = int(input())

tasks = []

def binarysearch(x):
    arr = tasks
    if arr == [] or x > arr[0]: return 0
    elif x < arr[-1]: return len(arr)
    l  = 0
    r = len(arr)
    while l <= r: 
        mid = int((l + r) / 2);
        if arr[mid] == x: 
            return mid 
        elif arr[mid] > x: 
            l = mid - 1
        else: 
            r = mid + 1
    return mid


for i in range(0, tasks_count):
    n = input().split(' ')
    if n[0] == '1':
        pos = binarysearch(int(n[1]))
        tasks.insert(pos, int(n[1]))
    elif len(tasks) < 3:
        print('Not enough enemies')
    else:
        print(tasks[(int(len(tasks)/3))])
```

Solution 2:

```
tasks_count = int(input())

tasks = []

for i in range(0, tasks_count):
    n = input().split(' ')
    if n[0] == '1':
        tasks.append(int(n[1]))
    elif len(tasks) < 3:
        print('Not enough enemies')
    else:
        tasks.sort(reverse=True)
        print(tasks[int(len(tasks)/3)-1])
```

Comment: 2 things.

1. You will get a Time Limit Exceeded even for a wrong answer if you have a loop or something that doesn't terminate.
2. Why are you binary searching? you should be using a stream sort like heap sort or insertion sort first! The input stream isn't sorted!

Comment: In question its asked for binary search and the second solution is correct for all answer just the time exceeded

Comment: @Srini Can you please remove the downvote? I have tried this for 2 hours and than i posted here what I am doing wrong

Comment: Hint: run your Solution 1 code locally with the following lines of input: `4`, `1 1`, `1 3`, `1 2`, `2`.

Comment: @RahulShrivastava wasn't me

Comment: But you're not searching for a specific value... You've just been asked to output the value at index `length_of_input_list//3`. That's not what binary search does. Maybe the coding challenge site you're using just isn't very good.

Answer (score 0):

Solution #2 is mostly on target, but it's got a few issues that needlessly slow it down. For one, the `input` function is a lot slower than directly reading from `sys.stdin`; from my brief experiments, it takes about 10x longer to loop over a `range` and call `input` than it does to loop over an `islice` of `sys.stdin`.

It also performs some rigmarole computing the index converting to `float` and back to `int` which could be avoided:

```
int(len(tasks)/3)-1
```

could be computed directly as:

```
len(tasks) // 3 - 1
```

using the `//` floor division operator to directly compute an `int`.

A minor improvement would be to split the lines with `str.partition` so you don't have to deal with manual indexing (which can be surprisingly slow, not to mention less obvious to read).

A final microoptimization would be to bundle up your work in a function call; CPython variable stores and loads at global scope entail `dict` operations, while at local scope, they're simple C array lookups that run faster.

Factoring in all of these, you'd end up with code more like:

```
import sys

from itertools import islice

def main():

    tasks_count = int(next(sys.stdin))

    tasks = []

    for line in islice(sys.stdin, tasks_count):
        task_type, sep, task_value = line.partition(' ')
        if task_type == '1':
            tasks.append(int(task_value))
        elif len(tasks) < 3:
            print('Not enough enemies')
        else:
            tasks.sort(reverse=True)
            print(tasks[len(tasks) // 3 - 1])

if __name__ == '__main__':  # Standard import guard
    main()  # Call main
```

If they're intentionally forcing frequent sorts, this may still be too slow (because while Python's TimSort tries to handle mostly sorted inputs efficiently, it's still quite a lot of work relative to simple indexing and appending). It's possible you may want to keep it sorted as you go using the `bisect` module (which implements your binary search for you, but in an extension module that runs much faster), in which case you remove the `sort` call entirely in favor of keeping it ordered as you insert (replacing `O(n log n)` work per task #2 with `O(n)` work per task #1). Conveniently, you don't have to keep it ordered by descending value, as Python allow negative indices, so it's equally easy (if not slightly easier) to compute the required index in the ascending direction:

```
import sys
from bisect import insort
from itertools import islice

def main():

    tasks_count = int(next(sys.stdin))

    tasks = []

    for line in islice(sys.stdin, tasks_count):
        task_type, sep, task_value = line.partition(' ')
        if task_type == '1':
            insort(tasks, int(task_value))  # Task 1 more expensive, O(n) instead of O(1)
        elif len(tasks) < 3:
            print('Not enough enemies')
        else:
            print(tasks[-(len(tasks) // 3)])  # Task 2 cheaper; O(1) instead of O(n log n)
```